# PHP-CS-Fixer Spaces around param and return types e.g. int|string -> int | string

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I've tried playing with the `binary_operator_spaces` rule with no luck e.g. variants of:

```
        "binary_operator_spaces": { "default":  "at_least_single_space",
            "operators": {
                "|": "single_space"
            }
        }
```

However was hoping there was a rule that can enforce spacing between return types and param types.

```php
function test(int|string $value): Model|string
```

should turn into

```php
function test(int | string $value): Model | string
```

Are there any rules that can be used for this?